# Insert existing item in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Consider Many-Many modelling between Customer & products. Customer is trying to buy a product with id say, 146. i.e product already exists in database. All I need to do is associate product id with the customer in database.

[image]

Below code should ideally, associate product id to the Customer object without doing a round trip to the database as below:

```
    public async Task<int> BuyProduct()
    {
        using (ProductsContextContainer ctx = new ProductsContextContainer())
        {
            var newCustomer = new Customer()
            {
                Id = r.Next(),
                FirstName = "John Doe",
                Products = new List<Product>
                {
                    new Product()
                    {
                        Id = 146
                    }
                }
            };

            ctx.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
            return await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

However along with customer above code tries to insert a new product product with id.

Thus I have to explicitly fetch Products object & then insert customer.

```
var boughtItem = ctx.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 146);
var newCustomer = new Customer()
{
    Id = r.Next(),
    FirstName = "John Doe",
    Products = new List<Product>
    {
        boughtItem
    }
};
```

In the back of my head I am able to guess that I need to use Entry method to associate exiting product. But not quite figure out how. Can you please help?

Comment: your scheme looks strange to me for many to many relationships. Normally you have a third table where `Customer` and `Product` is defined

Comment: @VDesign Entity model designer creates the third table behind the scene & abstracts it from user at C# level.